# WordPress 404 errors on all pages except home

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I'm having a really unique issue with a local development environment. I currently have a WAMP Stack Running on ZendServer. On my computer, by default, port 80 is occupied, so I am using port 8080, and I'm having no issues with this whatsoever.

This issue first came to my attention when I started with a local WordPress install, and I can view the homepage and access the backend of WordPress with no issues. I can add/edit posts with no issues. I originally set up a vhost to have zr‑www.mywebsite.com:8080 to map into my htdocs folder and that works with no issues.

What then happens is that I go on the home page, then try to go to any page other than the home page (on the front end), and I get a `404 Not Found` error. It is an exact clone of the live site, and when I test it on a linux-based LAMP Stack (Ubuntu) it works with no issues.

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a mod_rewrite issue. Is it installed and enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your WordPress rewrite rules. Make sure you enabled `mod_rewrite` and have the [appropriate bits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file's contents, I do not think that is the issue

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /trafficbarricade/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /trafficbarricade/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: That's only half the story. Do the other thing: Enable `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: It's enabled in the httpd.conf file (IE it's uncommented). I'm looking at the Mod_rewrite.so file and it basically looks like each row has 8 sets of 4 alphanumeric characters, is that right?

Comment: You restarted Apache after enabling mod_rewrite? Is it _really_ enabled?

Comment: I've mod_rewrite was always enabled as far as I know, how do I check f it's "really enabled" on windows?

Comment: Can I find out if mod_rewrite is really enabled in PHPinfo? If so, it is't listed there

Comment: I got it fixed. It was a mod_rewrite issue.